# Translate Google Chrome's storage from policies/managed/*.json to Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser-addons, storage

Google Chrome's extensions can be configured as a user by creating a file in `/etc/chromium-browser/policies/managed/` [containing e.g.](https://github.com/serv-inc/safe-search/wiki/Configure)

```
{
    "3rdparty": {
        "extensions": {
            "fiopkogmohpinncfhneadmpkcikmgkgc": {
                "youtube": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(in Linux, for Windows, you have to [set a group policy with similar content](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en))

How can this be translated to Firefox? How can Firefox's WebExtensions be configured (as a user, not as a developer) with [storage.managed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/managed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps more information is needed, but it seems to me that the question is answered
by your own link.

If you are the extension developer, you should include in the manifest file
[`manifest.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json):

```
"type": "storage",
"data":
{
  "whitelist": "google",
  "starttime": "0800",
  "endtime": "1500"
}
```

The attribute `whitelist` is referenced in the code by the
[StorageArea.get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/get) function:

```
var storageItem = browser.storage.managed.get('whitelist');
storageItem.then((res) => {
  console.log(`Whitelist is: ${res.whitelist}`);
});
```

If you would like to change an existing extension, then you need to do it
from source-code, since not only the manifest needs to be changed,
but also the code itself that references the storage items.
Even if the extension uses a
[Native manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_manifests),
defined as
"specially formatted JSON files that are provisioned on the user's computer by some means outside the extension installation process", changing 
the manifest is not enough.

The
[storage.managed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/managed)
page links to the example add-on of
[favourite-colour](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/favourite-colour), which is a complete example showing the definition,
access and setting of the managed data, and of creating the
`manifest.json` file.

Comment: The question could arguably be understood the way you answered it.It was useful (+1) in pointing out that it could be misunderstood. Hopefully, it is clearer now.

Comment: PS: Your link to `Native manifest` contains the "Managed storage manifests" part. That is what this question is about.

Comment: See [Native manifests - Manifest location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_manifests#Manifest_location).

Comment: See also [Porting a Google Chrome extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Porting_a_Google_Chrome_extension).

Comment: So what exactly should be the contents of that file? As you wrote above? And where should it be placed, say in Linux?

Comment: I have given you links to the right information. You will have to study it, since I can't tell you exactly what to do with your extension. The subject matter is large enough that real study is required, there are no shortcuts.

Comment: I tried this some time ago, it did not work. What to do? 1. install from [amo](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/sas/). 2. use configuration [at specified location](https://github.com/serv-inc/safe-search/blob/master/meta/examples/lock_moderate_youtube.json) 3. check that it is used by validating on youtube. If you set it to 2 (very strict), you should be unable to view any violent or adult content.

Comment: How does that relate to the question?

Comment: It is a way to show a practical example how to use managed storage on Firefox. If you want to use another browser extension that uses managed storage, and **show how it is configured on the user side**, feel free.

Comment: PS: the extension is already used on both Chrome and Firefox, as seen from the github repo. (re "See also Porting a Google Chrome extension")

Comment: The [storage.managed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/managed) page links as complete example to [favourite-colour](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/favourite-colour). It might be a better example.

Comment: That looks good.

Comment: If you feel that your question has been answered here, you might accept this answer.

Comment: If you would like an accept, you might edit the answer to reflect the favourite-color github sample.

Comment: Works like a charm. See the steps to reproduce below.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps to customize [the favorite-color extension](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/favourite-colour) provided by Mozilla:

1. download favorite-color extension at https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/favourite-colour
2. create file with manifest content at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/managed#Provisioning_managed_storage:

   ```
   {
     "name": "favourite-colour-examples@mozilla.org",
     "description": "ignored",
     "type": "storage",
     "data":
     {
       "colour": "management thinks it should be blue!"
     }
   }
   ```
3. `mkdir -p /usr/lib/mozilla/managed-storage` ([global install, can also save to `~/.mozilla/managed-storage` for a user-based install](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_manifests#Manifest_location))
4. save file to `/usr/lib/mozilla/managed-storage/favourite-colour-examples@mozilla.org.json`
5. start firefox (or ESR)
6. load extension downloaded in step 1 in `about:debugging`